# Trying to create multiple button clicks to automate a login process using Greasemonkey

Tags: function, authentication, greasemonkey-4

I am trying to setup an automated process for a visitor kiosk at my company. The idea is to schedule automatic weekly restarts followed by the browser launching to the network page, logging in under the kiosk account and then launching the kiosk program. The problem is with the login page. The login fields are staggered and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to simulate the mouse click to progress to the next field.

any help is hugely appreciated.

The format I've been trying. There's three copies of the same function for filling out a field, clicking the next button and progressing to the next field. field entry works fine but I have had no luck getting the button click to work.

```
function UserEnter(username) {
    // Find the input fields for username
    const usernameInput = document.querySelector('input[name="username"]');

    // Check if the input fields exist
    if (!usernameInput) {
        console.error("Username input field not found.");
        return;
    }

    // Enter the username
    usernameInput.value = username;

    // Find the button to click
    const button = document.querySelector(buttonSelector);

    // Check if the button exists
    if (!button) {
        console.error("Button not found.");
        return;
    }

    // Click the button
    button.click();
}
```

This is the container for the button I'm trying to use,

```
<div class="col-sm-12 btn-next-container">
 <button class="btn btn-default btn-auth btn-next" onclick="onUsernameEntered()" type="button">Next<i class="icon-next"></i></button> </div>
```

Is there a specific constraint I have to use for the click function to succeed? or is there an alternative way to click the button. after successfully clicking this button it will transition to the next entry field with another button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button click calls `onUsernameEntered()`. Maybe simply calling `onUsernameEntered()` solves your issue. If not, then:

```
document.querySelector(".btn-auth.btn-next").click();
```

but, if your button is not yet operational, then you can create a load handler for it:

```
document.addEventListener("load", function() {
    document.querySelector(".btn-auth.btn-next").click();
});
```

Comment: Thank you! calling for onUsernamedEntered() did the trick. slight new problem now. calling for password entry is hitting before the field is available. trying to use setTimeout to create a delay before it runs but it seems to not work.

Comment: @Kliessen try to do it inside a load listener, like in my second example. The function that's passed to addEventListener there is executed when the page has loaded. If my answer solved your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct solution.

Comment: took me a minute but figured it out. had to change the priority for the timeouts. everythings working great. thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Kliessen happy to help!